# \input and \include for a thesis

Tags: input, include

I'm writing a thesis but not modular style. I simply write everything in one big document and want to change it. But there is a problem.

For sections must not I start with `\begin{document}` again? Otherwise, it can't be compiled, but if I do it, for this time my document will have lots of begin command.

What can I do to continue with one document?

Comment: Could you please make a sentence of your title ? What you want is not exactly explicit. What do your mean by *modular style* and *there is a problem* ?

Answer (score 4):

You should input your `.tex` files in this way:

```
\documentclass[options]{theclass}

%preamble

\begin{document}
\section{section1name}
\input{sec1} %the file is sec1.tex 

\section{section2name}
\input{sec2} %the file is sec2.tex
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

So latex will *paste* the text where you call `\input{}`

include works quite the same but it starts a new page when you call `\include{}`

That would be the best strategy.

---

If you want just one file, then write the document in this way:

```
\documentclass[options]{article}

    %preamble

    \begin{document}
    \section{section1name}

    Write your text as 
    I am writing 
    write your text...

    \section{section2name}

    Same way 
    .
    .
    .
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, *both cases have just one begin-end document*.

If you want to avoid numbered sections use the starred command

```
\section*{}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `\input` and `\include` is *how* it's included, there is [an old discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) on how to use them.

No, you do `\begin{document}` things only once. Then you use `\include{chapter3}` once per chapter. You can basically cut the chapter text from the big document, place it into `chapter3.tex` and insert the include statement instead in the main document.

*Update:* Oh, an continuing scrying into your question: you compile the main document, as before. As the start of the compilation regarded, nothing changes for you that multiple included `*.tex` files are present.

I also recommend `latexmk` and `git` for more easy compilation and management of the source, but that's tangential.

Comment: And if OP really wants to compile the subfiles separately, then they'd wan to look into the `standalone` or `subfiles` packages.

Comment: Teepeemm: Excellent addendum! There are also solutions around `latex-preview` and overall wonderful AuCTeX, but emacs is not everyones favourite toy.